# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-34 does not boot after upgrading

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading to ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-34 my laptop does not boot, it freezes at the purple Ubuntu page. Even when trying with previous versions does not work. I have tried different options that I found on this and other websites. When entering in recovery mode I tried:

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
mount -o remount, rw/
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get clean
```

Nothing seems to work. The upgrade did not give any error. Any hint to solve this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- `Switch on` your computer.
- Wait until the Bios has finished loading.
- `Press` and `hold` the Shift key.
- Will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with: `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with: `recovery mode`
- Press `Enter` and your machine will begin the boot process.
- Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.
- One of the options will be: `Drop to root shell prompt`.
- Press Enter with this option highlighted.

In the terminal run the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
rm -rf /var/log/journal
rm -rf /run/log/journal
systemctl mask nfs-blkmap.service
apt-cache policy systemd-sysv
apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
apt-get remove chemical-mime-data
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
update-grub
apt-get clean
reboot
```